# Rails: How do I model preferences? Should I use has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, relationship

I have two models: User and HairColor. A user has only one hair color, but can have many hair color preferences. What's the best way to model this?

Here's what I started to do:

```
#models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hair_color
  has_many :preferences, 
  has_many :hair_colors, :through => :preferences
end

#models/hair_color.rb
class HairColor < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :users
end

#models/preference.rb
class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hair_color
end
```

Is using has_many :through the right approach? Also what if I want to extend this to other attributes such as "eye color"? (A user has one eye color, but can prefer many eye colors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a limited amount of hair colors, so the preference table needs to have a `hair_color_id` and be set up like so:

```
#models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :hair_color
  has_many :preferences
end

#models/hair_color.rb
class HairColor < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :preference
end

#models/preference.rb
class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :hair_color
end
```

I believe that's correct. Let me know if you run into any snags.

---

When you add eye color or any other characteristic, you'll probably have to do something different with preference. I'd have 4 columns at that point: `id, user_id, foreign_id, foreign_type`

foreign_id would be the id from the eye_color/hair_color table, and foreign_type would be "eye" or "hair" or something. Then in your model, you'd have something like this:

```
#models/hair_color.rb
class HairColor < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :preferences, :foreign_key => :foreign_id, :conditions => { "preferences.foreign_type" => "hair" }
end
```

That gets a little crazy, but it's the most DRY way of doing it. You'd put the same thing in your eye_color.rb and just replace "hair" with "eye" for the foreign_type.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out. Also, to add other preferences such as Eye Color, would I just need to add an `eye_color_id` column to the preference table? Or should I separate the preferences into distinct models, such as "HairColorPreference" and "EyeColorPreference"? Not sure which would be the most DRY.

Comment: Updated for further question.

Comment: Chuck, this is great. I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out and understand the has_many :through association. This does seem like the most DRY approach. So now, I'll try it out and then attempt to get a form working for selecting preferences within a view template. New to Ruby on Rails, but hopefully it's not too hard. Thanks!

Comment: No problem man! Rails is really confusing when you first get started, but after a while you start to appreciate it's conventions and the "magic" that goes on behind the scenes. Good luck!

Comment: Also, for future reference, most people I've seen use :through as simply a way to change their naming conventions. So if you wanted User.Choices, you'd have to put :has_many :choices, :through => :preferences. There are other uses for it, but don't over-estimate it's utility.

Comment: Working on this now, and just noticed the `has_one` relationship for hair color. With this, I would need to include a `user_id` column in the `hair_colors` table. This means the hair color fields would repeat very often. Would it be better to use `belongs_to :hair_color` within the User model instead? It seems it would be more DRY this way to have the foreign key inside the users table instead.

Comment: Also just notice that you have `has_many :preferences` in the HairColor model instead of User model in your second example. :-)